# Al Compilar, el Emulador no me muestra mi objeto Panel ni Menu

Tags: genexus

Estoy comenzando a desarrollar bajo Genexus 17 U3 full version. Mi primer app mobile.
La app  tiene un Menu, un Panel, pero no tiene que trabajar con objetos Transactions (eso me lo pidieron por definición), con variables y estructuras de datos que graben en el Client Storage del celular.

Configuré el Menu como Main Program. Creé un Action dentro del Menu que apunta al objeto Panel.
Pero cuando presiono F5, compila, abre el Emulador todo bien, pero no veo en el Emulador el objeto Panel que armé (le puse unos objetos TextBlocks dentro de un objeto Table, y solo para probar que carga el Panel, cree una variable que la igualo a  la variable se sistema Today dentro del Evento Start).

Solo me muestra Preferences\ User Information \Server URL   que no es ni mi Menu ni mi Panel.
Y si hago click en server URL me muestra :  http://10.0.2.2/VitaminaD.NetEnvironment/

No sé que me está faltando configurar para que el emulador me muestre mis objetos, y asi continuar el desarrollo.
Esta primer parte es como mi “Hola Mundo” pero que muestro en el panel la fecha de hoy….el tema es que no me muestra el Panel…

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a que leas la sección [¿Cómo creo un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que sigas los consejos y aumentes tus posibilidades de recibir una respuesta a tu problema. Para mas información puedes visitar la página de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Esa pantalla aparece si usas Dynamic Service Url = True, deberias ponerlo en false en tu caso. https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20366,Dynamic+Services+URL+property

Comment: Verificaria tener todos los requerimientos de .net , en particular url rewrite: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?14958,How+to+install+URL+Rewrite

Comment: Muchas gracias fpanizza. Parametrice en False la propiedad Dynamic Service URL y ahora sí al ejecutar el Emulador, llegue al objeto Menu. Al presionar el icono de una Action que le coloqué apuntando al objeto Panel, pasa a ese objeto pero muestra el error "An error ocurred on the aplication server (500 - Internal Server Error)". Busque en la Wiki de Genexus y encontré que debia verificar una configuracion en el IIS

Comment: En mi notebook tengo Win 10 con “IIS 10”, al seleccionar el NetEnviroment relacionado con mi App. Fui dentro de Acciones,  a Configuracion Avanzada, y reemplacé el valor contenido en “Grupo de aplicaciones” (Aplication Pool): “ASP.NET V4.0” por el correcto DefaultAppPool. Después de esto, probé hacer F5 pero me volvió a salir el error 500 - Internal Server Error...

Comment: Finalmente, como me sugeriste, instalé URL Rewrite Module 2.1     x64 Installer  (rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi) en mi equipo. Una vez instalado, me abrió correctamente el objeto Panel llamado desde el Action del objeto Menu. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

creo que te faltó setear el Panel como "Startup Object". Para ello solamente alcanza con hacer clic derecho sobre la pestaña del Panel y marcar la opción "Set as Startup Object"

[image: Set as Startup Object]

Comment: Habia configurado el Menu como Main Program = True y haciendo click en "Set As Startup Object", y por otro al Panel como Maun Program = False.  Al presionar F5, sin embargo, algo falta porque no veo en el Emulador el Menu ni el Panel.

Comment: Verifiqué: 
Dentro del Preferences BackEnd está Web Root: http://localhost/VitaminaD.NetEnvironment/

Dentro de Preference FrontEnd está:
• Dynamic Services URL: True
• Services URL: http://localhost/VitaminaD.NetEnvironment/

Y si presiono en la pantalla del Emulador  “Server URL”, muestra: http://10.0.2.2./VitaminaD.NetEnviroment/ 
Lo cambié a http://localhost/VitaminaD.NetEnvironment/ pero muestra el mismo error, al hacer click en OK, muestra: Your server URL is incorrect.

Comment: Esa pantalla aparece cuando usas Dynamic Services Url = true y no puede acceder al servidor. Te recomiendo probar con Dynamic Services Url = False. Si sigue con problemas, es que el emulador no accede a los servicios.  Revisaria el log : https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37846,HowTo%3A+Enable+logging+for+Smart+Devices